# WYSIWYG shortcode to AngularJS function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wordpress, angularjs-scope

I have a custom WordPress shortcode that when used in a WYSIWYG returns a bunch of html with an Angular function attached.

Below is an example of what I am trying to do.

**Shortcode:**

```
add_shortcode('example', function($atts) {
    extract(shortcode_atts([
        'string' => 'This is default text'
    ], $atts));

    ob_start();
        ?>
            <div class="example-layout">
                <div class="container">
                    <button ng-click="do_something('<?= $string; ?>')">
                        Click here
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
});
```

**Usage:** `[example string="Override default string"]`

**Returns:**

```
<div class="example-layout">
    <div class="container">
        <button ng-click="do_something('Override default string')">
            Click here
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Angular function:**

```
$scope.do_something = function(string) {
    alert(string);
};
```

This isn't going to work, but I am struggling to find a sensible solution.

Any help or advice would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
  <div class="container" ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
     <button ng-click="do_something('testClick')">CLICK ME</button>
  </div>
```

On Angular :

```
    function TodoCtrl($scope) {

      $scope.do_something = function (name){
         angular.isFunction($scope[name])
          $scope[name]()
         }

       $scope.testClick = function(){
          alert("Called");
         }
     }
```